# Firebase/React Native: App crashes on Android when attempting to generate a uploading tasks

Tags: javascript, android, typescript, react-native, firebase-storage

I'm implementing the image upload feature in a React Native app with Firebase. The code works well on iPhone; however, upon exporting the APK, the app crashes on the uploading screen. After some debugging, I discovered that the crash occurs precisely when the for loop is executed to generate uploading tasks.

```
const pickImage = async () => {
  let result = await ImagePicker.launchImageLibraryAsync({
    mediaTypes: ImagePicker.MediaTypeOptions.Images,
    selectionLimit: 4 - pickedImages.length,
    aspect: [1, 1],
    allowsMultipleSelection: true,
    quality: 1,
  });

  if (!result.canceled) {
    // for preview
    setPickedImages([...pickedImages, ...result.assets]); 
    
    // generate upload tasks
    for (let i = 0; i < result.assets.length; i++) {
      const storageRef = ref(storage, `deals/img_${uuid()}`);
      const response = await fetch(result.assets[i].uri);
      const blob = await response.blob();
      const task = uploadBytesResumable(storageRef, blob);
      setUploadTasks([...uploadTasks, task]); 
    }
  }
};
```

I don't know if there are specific requirements that need to be addressed to make it function correctly on android?